# How to test that URI is called only once

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking

I have this method:

```
def url
  @url ||= URI("#{API_BASE}/#{url_token}")
end
```

I want to test using rspec that the `URI` is called only once. However, as `URI` is a module, I have no idea of how to mock that.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you testing that? This sees like such a trivially ridiculous thing to test in the first place, no offense, as the cost of running URI on a string is nearly zero. So long as that function returns a value that's what you expect, such as a URI instance with the correct properties set, you should consider that a success.

If you are really dead-set on doing that for whatever reason then you need to think about how you could distinguish between a function written incorrectly and one written correctly, at least by your definition of correct (e.g. no duplicated calls).

I'd suggest doing something where you verify that calling it 10 times yields *exactly* the same `object_id` value on the result.

Comment: It's for the sake of learning. Thanks for the idea about checking the `object_id`